# What is the purpose of the comma after the と in 異変と、その影に潜む陰謀を、彼はまだ知らない。

Tags: grammar, meaning, punctuation

What is the reason for putting this comma in?

> **異変と**、その影に潜む陰謀を、彼はまだ知らない。

As I understand it, the sentence means that he doesn't (yet) know about either the 異変 or the 陰謀. Is this comma here meant to make the reader parse the sentence in a certain way?

Comment: It seems to me like the と here is used to say "as", so it kind of means he doesn't [yet] know the 陰謀 is a disaster. In such a case, the comma would make it clear that the clause following the comma is the one describing the 異変, and the final clause is the one acting on it. Though I'm not completely certain this is the case, it seems correct.

Answer (score 2):

While the logical meaning is the same with or without the comma, without it, the reader may feel like he doesn't know **one** thing:

> [ 異変とその影に潜む陰謀 ] を、彼はまだ知らない。

With the comma, it is much clearer that 彼 doesn't know **two** things:

> [ 異変 ] と、 [ その影に潜む陰謀 ] を、彼はまだ知らない。

It just emphasizes the 異変 more, and I think the pause matches the way a tasteful narrator would read the sentence out loud. I'd say the difference is similar to these two sentences:

1. He has yet to discover the anomaly, and the conspiracy behind it.
2. He has yet to discover the anomaly and the conspiracy behind it.